# When leave the application, SharedPreferences must be deleted

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a SharedPreferences that activates interstitial after every third action within the application. I want SharedPreferences to clear the settings when a user leaves the application so that interstitial can load after every application startup. Please help.

```
    SharedPreferences admob = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = admob.edit();

    // Save counter value back to SharedPreferences
    editor.putInt(COUNTER_INTERSTITIAL_ADS, mAdCounter);
    editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your cleanup(Shared Preferences Cleanup) code in the `onDestroy()` method, this is the last method that is called before an activity finally closes. For all the information on the Android activity life cycle have a look at the Android Documentation for: [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Sample Code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit.clear().apply();
```

Comment: Can you show me a specific example of how to make code? Thanks

Comment: this is not the right solution to the problem, is there another suggestion or solution? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put this dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:*"
```

Then in your Application class, use this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    private void onAppDestroyed() {
       //Clear data here
       SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       pref.edit.clear().apply();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private void onAppForegrounded() {
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
    }
}
```

Update your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ....>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code on the `onDestroy()` as @janDe said. Indeed it is the last method that gets called before a activity is "destroyed". The code to delete all of your shared preferences is this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit.clear().apply();
```

Basically what you do is get the preferences, go into edit mode(where you can edit the values) and say `clear()`. Then you can apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences admob = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = admob.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();  // or editor.commit() if on older API versions
}
```

Comment: onDestroy is less likely to be called. It's not guarenteed that it would be called every time.

Comment: this is not the right solution to the problem, is there another suggestion or solution? thank you!

Comment: You can delete your sharedpreferences as per your requirement, but before that study of Activity Life Cycle would help you to sort the issue. 
Like if you want to delete the data when app goes in background you must clear the preferences in onPause() method

Answer (score 0):

> I have a SharedPreferences that activates interstitial after every third action within the application. I want SharedPreferences to clear the settings when a user leaves the application so that interstitial can load after every application startup. Please help.

Instead thinking backward and trying to clean up the `SharedPreferences` at the end of your Application, why don't you just reset the `SharedPreferences` in startup? It's more cleaner solution for your case.

You can't depend on `onDestroy()` method to clean up the SharedPreferences because **there's no guarantee that it will be called when the application is terminated.**

So, you can solve the problem easily by reset the SharedPreferences when you start your related Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    // reset the counter
    editor.putInt(COUNTER_INTERSTITIAL_ADS, 0);
    editor.apply();

    ...

}
```

Comment: This idea makes sense, but it doesn't work, how do i integrate this line of code that resets the counter: `admob.edit().remove(COUNTER_INTERSTITIAL_ADS).apply();` Can you give me a specific example? thank you.